# how to parse a symbolic string to a double variable in C++?

Tags: c++, string

suppose I input a string from the keyboard which is like a mathematical function of x . Then I want to write a function that would take a double variable x and the string as its argument and then return the value by evaluating the string for any particular value of x.

Example

string mystr;

mystr = " x*x + 3*x";

Now I want to write a function

double func( double x, string str)

such that when called as

func( 2, mystr)

it should return the value 10 i.e  (2*2 + 2*3)

Comment: So, the standard question again.. what have you tried..? We don't write homeworks here..

Answer (score 3):

you can use an algorithm such as [this one](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm) to convert the string to postfix notation.  but whenever you encounter the `'x'` character, push the function argument onto the stack instead.

then, use an algorithm such as [this one](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/postfix-evaluation/index.htm) to evaluate that postfix representation to get the actual result